# How to select an element containing text with robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I want to select an element named Uncheck All.
The element is not a check box, it's a link.

i tried this:
//*[@class=n'g-scope ng-isolate-scope' and contains ('Uncheck All')

It can't find the element.

```
<div id="channel-groups-div-0" class="box-wrapper fn-toggle-content no- script" style="display: block;">
<div class="box-action">
<span id="deselect-all-0" class="select-all">Uncheck All</span>
<span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>
<span id="select-all-0" class="select-all">TCheck All</span>
</div>
```

Any help would be good, thank you

Comment: the html is: <span id="deselect-all-8" class="select-all">Unselect All</span>

Comment: the xpath you're using is looking for something with a class of `g-scope ng-isolate-scope`, but the html you showed doesn't have an element with that class.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, i re-edit the question with html code.

Comment: Why look for `class=n'g-scope ng-isolate-scope`, when the code clearly has a class of `select-all`? And does the code really use a class of `select-all` for both the check all and uncheck all buttons?

Comment: yes the class uses select-all for Check All and Uncheck All.

Comment: Your question says _"The element is not a check box, it's a link."_, but the html you provided doesn't contain a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This xpath will work for the code snippet you provided:

```
//span[@class='select-all' and text()='Uncheck All']
```